# Laravel . How to Get the start_date end_date of month, week or day of closed_at date in a filter

Tags: laravel

How to Get the start_date end_date of month, week or day of closed_at date in a filter.
i want to fetch start_date an end_date of closed_at
The two dates specify the beginning and the end of the period (day, week or month) that has been grouped by'closed_at'

```
public function scopeGroups($query, $period)
    {
        switch ($period) {
            case 'day':
                $query->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(closed_at, '%d')"));
                break;

            case 'week':
                $query->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(closed_at, '%u')"));
                break;

            case 'month':
                $query->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(closed_at, '%m')"));
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow, please add some more info on what exactly youre problem is

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is what I think youre looking for

```
public function scopeGroups($query, $period)
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    switch ($period) {
        case 'day':
            $query->whereBetween('closed_at', [$now->startOfDay(), $now->endOfDay()]);
            break;

        case 'week':
            $query->whereBetween('closed_at', [$now->startOfWeek(), $now->endOfWeek()]);
            break;

        case 'month':
            $query->whereBetween('closed_at', [$now->startOfMonth(), $now->endOfMonth()]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: no i want the start {day, week, month} date and end {day, week, month} date of closed_at ,, and groub them by closed_at date ....in case of month i fetch this data { "closed_at": "2012-03-08 00:00:00", "count": 2} but i want this output  { "start": "2012-03-01 00:00:00", "end": "2012-03-31 00:00:00", "count": 2}